# Unable to verify the element availability in a page using cucumberjs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm trying to get the Boolean value based on element availability in the page. When the element present in the page I can able to get **True**, but if the element not present getting the below error message:

```
No element found using locator: By(css selector, .Welcome)
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .Welcome)
```

I have tried with below combinations:

```
browser.findElement(by.className('Welcome')).isDisplayed()
browser.findElement(by.className('Welcome')).isPresent()
element(by.className('Welcome')).isDisplayed()
element(by.className('Welcome')).isPresent()
```

Comment: please post the relevant HTML

Comment: The element details displayed as <button class="Welcome"></button>.

Answer (score 0):

"When the element present in the page I can able to get True, but if the element not present getting the below error messagee"

That error is because you are calling `isDisplayed()`.  You can check if an element is present or not and it will return true/false and without an error. But if you call `isDisplayed()` on an element that is not currently present, you will get a `NoSuchElementError`.  That simply means the element doesn't exist yet.  If you need to wait for it to become present AND visible, then use [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Answer (score 0):

If the element is not always present on the DOM, but only under certain conditions then you can always assert the presence by first getting an array of all the elements by that specific css selector and then making sure the length > 0 (meaning at least one element was found):

```
element.all(by.className('Welcome')).count()
   .then(function(elementsFound){
      expect(elementsFound>0,'element not found').to.equal(true);
    })
```